# Import numpy raise import error numba needs numpy 1.21 or less

Tags: python, numpy

[I tried to import numpy and I recieved the following error: "raise ImportError("Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less")
ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less" we already downloaded numba 0.48 and numpy 1.18.1 and it still asks to use numpy 1.21 or less. can anyone helps me on this issue? I attached 2 screenshots, one is the code and the other one is the error message.Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfNLL.png)

Comment: You downloaded NumPy 1.18.1, but how did you install it? Did you create a clean environment, or overwrite the old installation? With `pip`, it would be `pip install numpy==1.18.1`.

Comment: Hi, I already fixed the problem. I used the command line in the terminal "pip install numpy==1.18.1" it uninstalled the numpy version 1.22, our version and installed 1.18.1 instead. Thanks for helping us

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using virtual enivrements, i suggest you install and use [ANACONDA](https://www.google.com/search?q=anaconda&oq=anaconda&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67j46i67l2j0i67j0i512l4j46i512.1468j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). 
Solution: 
for this error i think using `Numpy==1.21.4` and `Numba==0.53.0` will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, we already run python on VMware on Ubuntu and when we wrote pip show numpy it showed us that we use Numpy 1.22 even though we downloaded Numpy 1.18.1

Comment: > pip uninstall numpy , 
then make sure you have no numpy installed on your env, then
>pip install numpy==VERSION